# Ubuntu 22.04 Download speed extremly slow compared to windows 10

Tags: networking, drivers, dual-boot

yeah i indeed did read the other problems, and they didn't seem to have anything helpful for me.
My download speed on Ubuntu 22.04 is slow compared to how fast i download on Windows 10(dual boot)
Ubuntu, downloading anything, it gets sometimes rarely around 1mb and the most time it is around and under 100kb/s estimated time to download ROCm/AMD driver is 11h.

Speed test:
Windows 10: 40mb/s
Ubuntu: 10mb/s

Wired connection with Ethernet cat 8 cable, using TP-Link TL-WA850RE(i think, looks the same as mine)

Linux kernel version: 5.15.0-72-generic
Ubuntu on SSD

Comment: Same hardware (cable,...) for the Win download, right?  mb is megabits, not bytes, you meant that, right?  How much memory do you have and how much is free during the download?  Does your machine slow way down during the download (cursor freezes then jerks to new position, etc.)? Writes to ext4 filesystem on Ubuntu side?  (might save half the writes if non-journaling).What model SSD (and does it use SMR)? Does sound like the "slow copy" problem.